# What does "an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" mean in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

In Java 8 there is "Method Reference" feature.
One of its kind is "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type"

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type

Can someone explain what does "arbitrary object of particular type" mean in that context ?

Comment: Of particular type = a String, or an Integer, or a MyClass, or... Arbitrary object = some instance of the type, for example, for type String, "abf" or "another string".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a reference to an instance method from some type. In the case of the example, `compareToIgnoreCase` is a method from `String`. The program knows that it can invoke this method on an instance of `String`, so it can take the reference and any object of that type and be guaranteed the method exists.

I would compare this to the `Method` class in that they refer to a method and can be invoked on an arbitrary instance of some type.

For the example, it can use two `String` objects and call `compareToIgnoreCase` on one and use the other as an argument to match the method signature. This allows it to take the array and sort it based on any method of the array type instead of requiring a comparator instance to do this instead.

And here is the example for anyone who didn't click on the link in the question:

```
String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
"Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda", "George" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Well explained buddy.

Answer (score 30):

The example given from the Oracle Doc linked is:

```
String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John", "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

The lambda equivalent of

```
 String::compareToIgnoreCase
```

would be

```
(String a, String b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)
```

The `Arrays.sort()` method is looking for a comparator as its second argument (in this example). Passing `String::compareToIgnoreCase` creates a comparator with `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)` as the compare method's body. You then ask well what's `a` and `b`. The first argument for the compare method becomes `a` and the second `b`. Those are the arbitrary objects, of the type String (the particular type).

Don't understand?

- Make sure you know **what a comparator is and how to implement it**.
- Know what a **functional interface** is and how it affects lambdas in Java.
- A **comparator is a functional interface** that's why the method reference becomes the body of the compare method inside the comparator object.
- Read the **source below for another example** at the bottom of the page.

Read more at the source:
http://moandjiezana.com/blog/2014/understanding-method-references/

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link, it helped me out :)

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 6):

Please see the below code sample which explains "*Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type*" category described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Person{
    String name;

    //constructor
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    //instance method 1
    public int personInstanceMethod1(Person person){
        return this.name.compareTo(person.name);
    }

    //instance method 2
    public int personInstanceMethod2(Person person1, Person person2){
        return person1.name.compareTo(person2.name);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        Person[] personArray = {new Person("A"), new Person("B")};
    
        // Scenario 1 : Getting compiled successfully
        Arrays.sort(personArray, Person::personInstanceMethod1);
    
        // Scenario 2 : Compile failure
        Arrays.sort(personArray, Person::personInstanceMethod2);
    
        // Scenario 3 : Getting compiled successfully. 
        Person personInstance = new Person("C");
        Arrays.sort(personArray, personInstance::personInstanceMethod2);

        // Scenario 4 : Getting compiled successfully. As the same way as "Scenario 1"
        String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
                                "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
        Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
    }

}
```

Scenario 1 and Scenario 4 describes "Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" category described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

If the method parameter takes a variable in same instance Type as the instance Type of the element, you can call that instance method using Type.(`Person::personInstanceMethod1`)

Compare "`personInstanceMethod1`" instance method in "`Person`" class with "`compareToIgnoreCase`" instance method in "`String`" class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) to see the similarity. Both are taking a single parameter with the same Type.

Compare Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 to see the difference.

Comment: Nice work, both creating a your own example class and methods plus illustrating the crucial differences between the three different scenarios.

Comment: very nicely explained Viraj !!

Comment: I was scratching my head for the longest time why it was possible to pass String::concat as a comparator without referencing a particular String object. So the syntax for a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type is "ContainingType::methodName". So, just to be clear, the type of methodname's parameters must exactly match the type of ContainingType, correct? So if you defined a class Person2 with the exact same "instance method 1" as class Person, then Arrays.sort(personArray, Person2::personInstanceMethod1) will fail to compile?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a case where understanding the concept is made harder by the use of undefined terminology on the documentation.

Keep in mind that a method reference, as a type of lambda, implements a functional interface, and that ANY method that matches the signature of the interface can be used as long as you can reference it in your program.

Of the four kinds of method references, which represent different ways needed to access (reference) the method. The syntax of three are pretty straightforward: If it is a static method then you use the class name before the :: operator, if it is an instance method in an object then you generally use a reference variable for the object, or if it a constructor you use ClassName::new.

The fourth kind is where you want to call a method that is an instance method of a parameter passed to the function. With a lambda, there is no problem because you can reference the parameter variable, like this:

```
(String someString) -> someString.toLowerCase();
```

However, since there is no explicit parameter variable in a method reference, the syntax used instead is:

```
String::toLowerCase;
```

The compiler takes the "particular type" (String) to reference the functional method (toLowerCase) contained in an "arbitrary object" (the object passed in the parameter).
The term "arbitrary object" is used because the actual object passed in the parameter could be different each time the method reference is executed.

Comment: Thanks! What's confusing about method reference is the fact that the rule "ANY method that matches the signature of the interface can be used" can be broken
IE: take an Optional<Product>, Product obj. contains field "price" 
I can say
optional.map(Product::getPrice)

map method defined as: 
<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) 

Meaning "U" can be any new type, but the parameter type of the Function MUST be Product. Yet method referenced (getPrice) takes 0 args as it's a getter method. So the signatures don't match, that rule is broken. Yet it still compiles ???

Comment: The "instance passed to the function" part is what made it click for me. Cause it looks like you're calling a static method... except you're not, so how does it know what instance to call? But it makes sense because the instance is known when it gets passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it another way. So, if your lambda expression looks like the following:

```
(<ContainingType arg>, <otherArgs>) -> arg.instanceMethod(<otherArgs>)
```

It can be replaced with method reference such as

```
ContainingType::instanceMethod
```

So, for the lambda expression

```
(String a, String b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)
```

It can be replaced with method reference such as

```
String::compareToIgnoreCase
```

Here, the **particular type is the ContainingType which is String**. And an **instance of it (String) is arbitrary** since we haven't declared or initialized it yet and these are simply the arguments here. And hence "*arbitrary object of particular type*" in this context is "*arbitrary object of String type*"

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is using the same String::compareToIgnoreCase example. To better understand this consider following example with all reference types togather:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Consumer<String> con = str-> StringPrinter.staticPrint(str);
        //using static method ref
        con = StringPrinter::staticPrint; 

        StringPrinter prtr = new StringPrinter();
        con = str-> prtr.instancePrint(str);
        //using instance method ref
        con = prtr::instancePrint;
        

        BiConsumer<StringPrinter, String> biCon = (pp,str)->pp.instancePrint(str);
        //using instance method ref of an arbitrary object of particular type
        biCon = Printer::instancePrint; //notice stringPrinter object of Printer type
        
        //constructor ref
        Supplier<StringPrinter> sup = StringPrinter::new; 
    }
}


interface Printer {
    public void instancePrint(String msg);
}

class StringPrinter implements Printer{
    public static void staticPrint(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Static: " + msg);
    }

    public void instancePrint(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Instance: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case there is an array of  objects of a particular type(String) and  any random object in array can call its instance method . This approach allows a class to refer to its instance method as if it is a static method .

Also this approach works only for built in class of java like String but not for user defined class . In case of user defined class the instance method can only be referred by its object .