# Java 8 Lambda translation with incompatiable arguments

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-interface

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GomanTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        IntStream.of(2, 3, 1).collect(Container::new, Container::add, null);
    }
}


class Container<T> {

    void add(T t) {
        System.out.println("this is container " + t);
    }
}
```

output:

```
this is container 2
this is container 3
this is container 1
```

This runs successfully on 1.8.0_45.jdk. How does Container#add get translated to ObjIntConsumer#accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `Container.add` is an instance method which requires an instance to be invoked on. Since a method reference on the form `ClassName::methodName` is not bound to an instance, `Container::add` has a functional signature of `(Container<T>,T)`.

As you didn’t specify type arguments for `Container` nor a target type, the compiler will infer `Container<Object>`. So `Container::add` has the inferred signature `(Container<Object>,Object)` here, which is appropriate for the `accept` method of `ObjIntConsumer<Container<Object>>`, which has the signature `(Container<Object>,int)`.

The second argument can *accept* a value of type `int`, as, after boxing it to `Integer`, it is assignable to `Object`.

The same works if you assign the result to a variable, thus providing a target type, of `Container<Object>` or `Container<Integer>` like

```
Container<Integer> collected
   = IntStream.of(2, 3, 1).collect(Container::new, Container::add, null);
```

Any type argument which can consume an `Integer`, e.g. `Serializable` or `Number`, will work as well.

---

You can read more about unbounded references to instance methods in [“What does ‘an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type’ mean in java 8?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23533345/2711488).

---

As a side note, the `collect` methods of streams are not supposed to accept `null` arguments and the `Stream` implementation doesn’t. That passing `null` works with the primitive streams is a glitch in the current implementation and code which passes `null` is likely to break in the next version. As [Tagir Valeev pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584049/32584257?noredirect=1#comment53023224_32584257), the behavior has already [changed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/diff/013baa71b58b/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java) in the current development state of Java 9.

Comment: By the way, I’m surprised that `IntStream` accepts `null` as last argument to `collect`. The standard `Stream` implementation does not.

Comment: It's [already fixed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/diff/013baa71b58b/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java) in JDK-9, thus I would not write it this way

Comment: My confusion is not around boxing, unboxing. I provide method with one argument "add(T t)" but that gets translated to 2 arguments accept(T t, int value). I expect something like this:

    required: java.lang.Integer
    found: java.lang.Integer,int
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: The `Container.add` method is *not* `static`. Therefore it requires a `Container` instance to invoke it, *plus* an instance of `T` to pass as argument. Makes a *functional* signature of `(Container<T>,T)`. See [“What does ‘an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type’ mean in java 8?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23533345/2711488).