# How pass methods as parameters in Java using method reference notation (Class::method)?

Tags: java

I want to create method in a `Utils` class that accepts two parameters, the first is the domain class, and the second is a method from the domain class (passed as reference). This `Utils`' class has a method that will create an instance of the class and execute the method in the scope of the domain class instance.

For example, the domain class:

```java
public class DomainClass {
  
  public void dummyMethod() {}
  
}
```

The Utils class:

```java
public class Utils {

  public static void execute(Class<?> clazz, Runnable referenceMethod) {
     Object objInstance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
     // execute the 'referenceMethod' on the scope of 'objInstance'
  }

}
```

The call I want is something like: `Utils.execute(DomainClass.class, DomainClass::dummyMethod)`. However, this scenario has some problems:

1. How can I pass this parameters for the `Utils`class (now I'm having some compilation problems)?
2. How can I call the 'referenceMethod' with the scope of 'objInstance'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DomainClass::dummyMethod` is a reference to an instance method, and you need to provide an object  instance to run it. This means it cannot be a `Runnable`, but it can be a `Consumer` for example.

Also, it will help to make the `execute` method generic:

```
    public static <T> void execute(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> referenceMethod) {
        try {
            T objInstance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            referenceMethod.accept(objInstance);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Now you can call `execute` like this:

```
    Utils.execute(DomainClass.class, DomainClass::dummyMethod);
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason why this work? I've seen this tutorial from [MKYong](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-consumer-examples/) and it don't bind with what you showed me.

Comment: It's a "Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" there's a short description in the official tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html and a longer discussion with this stackoverflow question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533345/what-does-an-arbitrary-object-of-a-particular-type-mean-in-java-8